# Any suggestions for a small complex dataset with a binary outcome

Tags: prediction

and thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out here!
I am working with a small and complex dataset:
Approximately 14 patients who underwent surgery for a mental health condition.
I have very complex clinical and neuroimaging data from pre-surgery. Postoperatively at 12 months followup, patients are classified as having a good outcome, or bad outcome
I’m looking for potential predictors of this outcome. I know I have WAY less data than is optimal, but I’d like to try to identify some predictors. Are there any methods you’d suggest?
The potential number of pre-treatment predictors is about 30/patient (although I can perform the imaging analysis differently to have more or less)
Thank you!

Comment: Please can you describe the dataset in more detail, in particular the possible predictors/covariates otherwise this question risks being closed.

Comment: Some further detail on the dataset: Each subject has variables such as: Age, depression rating, anxiety rating, quality of life rating (all numbers), and several other clinical and cognitive scores. They also have done resting state fMRI, which I have analyzed quite a lot to generate multiple connectivity metrics for each subject, as well. The outcome is determined at 12 months, based on their depression or anxiety rating scale, and each subject is classified as a "responder" or "non-responder"

Comment: *"to generate multiple connectivity metrics"*. So how many potential predictors do you have ? Please edit the question, rather than making comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've now edited the initial question

Comment: How many good outcomes and how many bad out of the 14 total?

Comment: Approximately 7/14 good outcomes, 7/14 poor outcomes

Answer (score 1):

With only 7 cases in each outcome class, as you recognize you are substantially under-powered to determine any reliable relationships between your predictors and outcome. The usual rule of thumb for evaluating binary outcomes is that you should have about 15 cases in the lower-prevalence outcome group per predictor that you are evaluating. On that basis you only have half as many cases as would typically be needed just to evaluate a single predictor.

You could consider this a pilot project to try to identify specific predictors to evaluate in a later, more substantial study. But even that would pose problems both with false-positive and false-negative findings based on your present data sample.

For example, say you just took each of the good-outcome and bad-outcome cases separately and evaluated the differences between those 2 groups in terms of each of your 30 potential predictors individually.* If you accepted a *p* value of 0.05 as significant, that means you have nearly an 80% probability ($1-(0.95)^{30}\approx 0.785$) of finding at least one false-positive result. To prevent yourself by being led astray by a false-positive finding, you would need to take some precaution with respect to [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

On the other hand, with only 7 in each group at that significance level you have a 20% chance of not detecting a truly significant difference as large as 1.5 times the standard deviation among the values within a group. So you also risk being misled by an apparently non-significant result that occurred just by chance.

Although [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) is often used to select from among a set of predictors when there are more predictors than cases, with your sample size it would seem unlikely to return more than 1 predictor at minimum cross-validation error, and if you repeated the experiment you might well get a different predictor selected.

One approach you might consider for evaluating multiple predictors is a [boosted classification tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting). This has the advantage of being able to handle multiple predictors (and their interactions, if desired) while providing some protection from overfitting by "learning slowly" at each step of the process and by limiting the number of trees in the model. It also can provide estimates of relative importance of each of the predictors in the model, which might be a guide to future study. I don't, however, have any experience with using boosted trees with such small data sets and don't know how well they can be expected to perform.

You certainly should proceed to evaluate the data you have, but you need to keep your eyes wide open to the limitations.

---

*This type of individual assessment of course does not allow controlling for other predictors in the process.

Answer (score 0):

In a less sensitive scenario (the one more open to a venture bet) I would recommend some kind of transfer learning to partially compensate for the lack of data.

E.g., use a pre-trained general image-recognition model, and fine-tune it on your data (maybe even freezing it to avoid overfitting and only training your added layers).

Still, this is very prone to overfitting. As this can affect lives, definitely validate your findings with domain experts (to avoid situations where the model learned some markings on the margins of the images).